# Quote about using accurate words (e.g. not to exaggerate beauty) to not wear down their meaning

Tags: quote-source

Many years ago, I seem to recall, I read a quote that discouraged the use of superlative words for mundane events, arguing that then, when we found something truly superlative before us, we'd find ourselves short of words to adequately describe what is remarkable in it.

I believe the author was English and the example talked of prettiness and beauty, but I'm missing the wording and the author.

I'm sorry for the vague description, but my memory refuses to help any further! I would very much like to pinpoint the exact quote.

Comment: Was the quote written in a witty/humorous way or a profound/philosophical way? I feel like Terry Pratchett might have said something like this ...

Comment: I'm inclined to say "both", but likely leaning towards "deep", or "heartfelt". Stripping any poetry out of it, it could be something like "Do not use superlatives lightly. If you call all girls you like 'beautiful', what word is left to do justice to one that you find otherwordly attractive?". That said, I'm afraid I've never (knowingly) read Pratchett, so he might not be the culprit this time.